# how to use awk for two columns and more than 2 conditions

Tags: regex, awk

I would like to use awk to extract some information from my data.

As an example I have a data with 5 column
I would like to extract based on col1 and col2
Extract all lines where col1 is 'a' and col2 starts with 'LINE' or 'SINE' or 'ERV'

i tried

```
awk '{if ($1 == "a" && $2 ~ /SINE/ || $2 ~ /LINE/ || $2 ~ /ERV/ ) print $0}' myData.txt
```

Somehow this is not working

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: You have `$12` where I would have expected `$2`.

Comment: fixed the $2 mistake, thanks

Comment: Your command looks fine. what's not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
awk '$1 == "a" && $2 ~ /^(LINE|SINE|ERV)/' myData.txt
```