# Awk with two condition

Tags: unix, awk

I'm a little confused, how to print lines in unix **only if** `two condition is True`. I have a tab delimited file with 12 columns.

1 and 7 column is alphabetical, 6 and 12 is numeric.

I want to print line `if $1 = $7 and $6 = $12` only.

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Dead all? This is not Dead Overflow :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use awk for two columns and more than 2 conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710379/how-to-use-awk-for-two-columns-and-more-than-2-conditions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk '$1==$7 && $6==$12' file
```